# take values from array

Tags: php

How i can take this values from the sencond key [post_data]

```
Array ( [action] => woocommerce_update_order_review [security] => 5b6fd5503c [country] => SM [postcode] => 81569 [city] => asuncion [address] => nonombre [address_2] => 2 [s_country] => SM [s_postcode] => 81569 [s_city] => asuncion [s_address] => nonombre [s_address_2] => 2
```

/*this array**/

```
[post_data] => billing_anrede=Herr&billing_titel=Prof.&billing_first_name=Testing&billing_last_name=Testing+nachname&billing_address_1=nonombre&billing_address_2=2&billing_company=nonombre&billing_email=info%40as.com&billing_phone=%2B77+7789+78893&billing_postcode=81569&billing_city=asuncion&billing_country=SM&losung=&_n=3a2e28f947&_wp_http_referer=%2Fv2%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin-ajax.php )
```

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking.

Comment: for example echo ['post_data']->billing_anrede[0]; something like that, i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this PHP build in function [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
$post_data = array();    
parse_str($first_array['post_data'],$post_data);
$item_you_want = $post_data[1]; //second
$item_you_want = $post_data['billing_titel']; //second by key
```

Comment: That should work but parse_str() doesn't return any value, no need for "$second data = " . Also you may need to definre $postdata = array(); previously.

Comment: @jorge-orpinel
Updated answer, now this looks better.

Comment: (feel free to up my comment, I need reputation :D )